# How to use setter and getter in javascript, I met a error

Tags: javascript

My English is not good, but I will try my best to explain my question simply.
Description: Alert result is 1, I don't why, I think this should be 2015 to alert.

```
    var book = {};
    Object.defineProperties(book, {
            _year: {
                value: 1
            },
            edition: {
                value: 23
            },
            year: {
                get: function () {
                    return this._year;
                },
                set: function (newValue) {
                    if (newValue > 2004)
                        this._year = newValue;
                }
            }
        }
    );
    book.year = 2015;
    alert(book.year);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add *writable: true* like this

```
_year: {
  value: 1,
  writable: true
},
```

for __year_.

From [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties):

> writable
>
> true if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed with an assignment operator. 
>   Defaults to **false**.

Comment: nice catch; i was wondering why i don't see defineProperties() used more often. Note that when you use the more common Object.defineProperty() on an existing object property, that flag is already set, so you wouldn't need writeable explicitly mentioned.

Comment: @dandavis: Actually, I've working mainly on JavaScript for quite a while and I have **never** heard about it. Gonna definitely look into it more.